# Как скрыть скролл в mozilla, но оставить возможность скролить?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите как скрыть скролл в mozilla, но оставить возможность скролить? В в opera и chrome все отлично, но в mozilla не работает, может кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? Спасибо

https://jsfiddle.net/jb9Lcv2d/3/

```js
function scrollCompare() {

  let speed = 2; 

  let scroll = document.querySelector('.compare__body');
  let scrollMainBlock = document.querySelector('.compare__main-column');

  let left = 0;
  let drag = false;
  let coorX = 0;

  scroll.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    drag = true;
    coorX = e.pageX;
    console.log(1);
  });

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    drag = false;
    left = scroll.scrollLeft;
  });

  scroll.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (drag) {
      this.scrollLeft = left - (e.pageX - coorX) * speed;
    }
  });

  scroll.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    if (window.innerWidth > 768)
      scrollMainBlock.style.transform = 'translateX(' + this.scrollLeft + 'px)';
    else scrollMainBlock.style.transform = '';
  });

  window.addEventListener('resize',
    e => scroll.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('scroll'))
  );
};

scrollCompare();
```

```css
.compare__body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 400px;
}

.compare__main-row {
  width: 310px;
  min-height: 80px;
  background: red;
}

.compare__product-row {
  width: 330px;
  min-height: 80px;
   background: yellow;
}


.compare__body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="compare__wrap">
  <div class="compare__block">
    <div class="compare__scroll">
      <div class="compare__content">
        <div class="compare__body">
          <div class="compare__main-column">
            <div class="compare__main-row head-row"></div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
          </div>
          <div class="compare__product">
            <div class="compare__product-row head-row"></div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
          </div>
          <div class="compare__product">
            <div class="compare__product-row head-row"></div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
          </div>
          <div class="compare__product">
            <div class="compare__product-row head-row"></div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
          </div>
          <div class="compare__product">
            <div class="compare__product-row head-row"></div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
          </div>
          <div class="compare__product">
            <div class="compare__product-row head-row"></div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
function scrollCompare() {

  let speed = 2; 

  let scroll = document.querySelector('.compare__body');
  let scrollMainBlock = document.querySelector('.compare__main-column');

  let left = 0;
  let drag = false;
  let coorX = 0;

  scroll.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    drag = true;
    coorX = e.pageX;
    console.log(1);
  });

  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    drag = false;
    left = scroll.scrollLeft;
  });

  scroll.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (drag) {
      this.scrollLeft = left - (e.pageX - coorX) * speed;
    }
  });

  scroll.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    if (window.innerWidth > 768)
      scrollMainBlock.style.transform = 'translateX(' + this.scrollLeft + 'px)';
    else scrollMainBlock.style.transform = '';
  });

  window.addEventListener('resize',
    e => scroll.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('scroll'))
  );
};

scrollCompare();
```

```css
.compare__body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 400px;
}

.compare__main-row {
  width: 310px;
  min-height: 80px;
  background: red;
}

.compare__product-row {
  width: 330px;
  min-height: 80px;
   background: yellow;
}

.compare__body {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
.compare__body::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

```html
<div class="compare__wrap">
  <div class="compare__block">
    <div class="compare__scroll">
      <div class="compare__content">
        <div class="compare__body">
          <div class="compare__main-column">
            <div class="compare__main-row head-row"></div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
            <div class="compare__main-row">Цена</div>
          </div>
          <div class="compare__product">
            <div class="compare__product-row head-row"></div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
          </div>
          <div class="compare__product">
            <div class="compare__product-row head-row"></div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
          </div>
          <div class="compare__product">
            <div class="compare__product-row head-row"></div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
          </div>
          <div class="compare__product">
            <div class="compare__product-row head-row"></div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
          </div>
          <div class="compare__product">
            <div class="compare__product-row head-row"></div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
            <div class="compare__product-row">1002</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```